# Display what has been copied by `cp` (using `ksh`)

Tags: ksh, cp

I'd like to get output showing what has been copied by `cp`.
The only problem is how to do it when I `cp` many files at a time. For instance, `cp ./sourceDir/* $destinationPath/`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like Lawrence has mentioned, you can use

```
cp -v
```

to enable "verbose" mode, which displays the files you copy. Something else that might be useful is

```
cp -v > foo
```

which will output the list of files to a file called `foo`. This is useful if you're going to copy a lot of files and you want to be able to review the list later.

Answer (score 5):

`cp -v` enables verbose mode which displays what's being copied.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your system has the `-v` option to `cp`.

If it doesn't, you can make a loop to show the file names and copy them one by one. This is not completely straightforward if you want to keep track of whether some copies failed.

```
err=0
for x in ./sourceDir/*; do
  echo "$x -> $destinationPath/${x##*/}"
  cp "$x" "$destinationPath/" || err=1
done
return $err
```

Alternatively, you might use a tool with many options such as rsync.

```
rsync -av ./sourceDir/ "$destinationPath/"
```

Going in the other direction, you might find it enough to see the expansion of the wildcard.

```
echo "Copying files:" ./sourceDir/*
cp ./sourceDir/* "$destinationPath/"
```

Or you might print a trace of shell commands:

```
set -x
cp ./sourceDir/* $destinationPath/
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting what to do if the `-v` option is unavailable.